# Visual studio 2015 - Unable to launch until login

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 offline [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48146) and also update 1 [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49989).

I did not launch VS2015 after installation, I'm trying to launch after installation of update 1, but on launch, a login window opens asking username and password, but my system isn't connected to the internet.

The same is working on another system which is connected to the internet.

Comment: well I guess you have to connect to the internet once in a while

Comment: No, It is not allowed